# How to add custom nameservers for domain in VPS?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, bind, nameserver

I have a newly installed ubuntu 12.04 server. And I have also installed webmin+virtualmin. I am wondering how to manage nameservers (e.g ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com) for my domain to point server.

*P.S I have searched a lot, couldn't find anything useful.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for **dns glue record** http://faq.domainmonster.com/dns/glue_record/

Many domain registrars such as Name.com, EasySpace.com support glue records.

Using them, you can  setup the ns1.yourdomain.com and ns2.yourdomain.com to point to the whatever IP address you like that will be serving as your name server.

Further, I would recommend to use bind (named) as your DNS server.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

Are you wanting to

- Set up the nameservers on your new 12.04 (let's call it *monkey*)
  server so *monkey* can resolve addresses by using a specific
  nameserver (like Google's DNS).

OR

- Point your domain (e.g. example.com)
  to your new server so you can access it by browsing to
  http://example.com/

In the case of the former, you will need to edit /etc/resolv.conf and add the nameservers IPs to the file. If you wanted to add Google's DNS to your list of DNS servers, you'd add 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to that file.

If you're trying to point your domain (example.com) at your new server, you will need to refer to your domain registrar's documentation. Who did you register the domain with? Joker/GoDaddy/etc?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I want to have nameservers such as ns1.mydomain.com, ns2.mydomain.com and on GoDaddy fill domain dns information with those.

Comment: **Why** do you need servers like ns1.mydomain.com in the first place? Are you a domain reseller? Also, who do you host your VPS with?